# Generic constraint to not allow primitive types

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method:

```
public static DataTable ConvertCollectionToDataTable<T>(IList<T> list)
```

I want to limit this method to **not** allow `T` to be primitive types like `int`, `string`* and `bool`. This is because I want my method `ConvertCollectionToDataTable` only to accept objects that have properties. Each property of `T` will be converted to the value of a column. If the object doesn't have properties like, there are no rows to include in the DataTable. I prefer a compile time check.

The method would look something like this:

```
public static DataTable ConvertCollectionToDataTable<T>(IList<T> list) where T : not struct
```

(notice the not)

Unfortunately that doesn't work, is there a solution that does?

A solution to let all my `T` classes inherit from a Interface and setting where `T : ICustomInterface` is not a good solution for me, due to the large amount of classes.

*Like @Tim Schmelter states, a string is not a primitive type, but it would pass the `class` constraint.

Comment: Nothing built into the language. You could write an analyzer.

Comment: What about `class` instead of `not struct`. Not sure if that covers everything you want to prevent.

Comment: `String` is not a "primitive" but a reference type/class

Comment: @Igor `class` does not match my criteria, as `string` is also a (reference type)/class.

Comment: @Jelle: Maybe you can restrict on a specific interface like `IFooConvertible` which your classes implement

Comment: What is it you want your method to do that you do not want done on type `string`? Add some additional context to see if it even matters or not if `string` is allowed. Otherwise write an analyzer, that could offer some help. Obviously you could add runtime checks but that is not as restricting as compile time checks.

Comment: But `not struct` *also* wouldn't match your criteria, for the same reason...

Comment: Is `ConvertCollectionToFoo` descriptive of what you actually want to do? Convert a generic collections to tbd type `Foo` ?

Comment: @Igor I detailed my question. In short; consider `Foo` a `DataTable`.

Comment: "If the object doesn't have properties like, there are no rows to include in the DataTable" - which sounds like something simple for consuming code to deal with *if* it happens to pass any "non-property-having" types to it - and you don't need to ask for special language support for it.

Comment: @Jelle: Even if there was such a constraint that allows you to restrict on classes which are not string, that would not help you with your requirement. You would still allow classes which don't have (public) properties. So in my opinion either just use `class` or really use a common interface for all types that you allow. Is this a public Api or why it's so important?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Of classes indeed, I updated the question. And yes, it's very close to a public API. I'll go for `class` and add a analyzer.

Comment: @Jelle: Even a `class` constraint could be wrong, why this should be disallowed: `struct User{public string Name {get;set;}}`? So i would go with a proper documentation and return a `null` `DataTable`(or even throw an ArgumentException) if the type did not contain public properties.

Comment: I would consider using attributes to mark the types/properties you want to use, similar to how some serialization libraries do it. This should let users define what properties or fields to include/exclude. While it would not cause compile time errors, a "You need to decorate 'MyType' with 'ToDataTableAttribute'" runtime error is fairly easy to understand and fix.